# Strange behavior of BinCounts

Tags: list-manipulation, bugs, counting

**Bug introduced in 8.0 and fixed in 10.0.0**

---

Just try this example:

```
lst = {0, 1, 1, Sqrt[2], Sqrt[5], 2 Sqrt[2], 2, Sqrt[13], Sqrt[5], Sqrt[6], Sqrt[11], 
       Sqrt[14], Sqrt[11], Sqrt[10], 3 Sqrt[2], Sqrt[17], Sqrt[13], 2 Sqrt[5], Sqrt[29], 
       2 Sqrt[2]};

ex1 = BinCounts[lst, {Range[0, 18]}]
ex2 = BinCounts[lst, {Range[0, 19]}]
ex3 = BinCounts[N@lst, {Range[0, 18]}]
```

> ```
> {1, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> {1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> {1, 3, 6, 6, 3, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0}
> ```

Seems that `BinCounts` failed to notice the irrational numbers in `ex1`:

```
Select[lst, IntegerQ]
```

> ```
> (* This result is consistent with ex1. *)
> {0, 1, 1, 2}
> ```

Is it a bug? I'm using *Mathematica 8.0.4, Windows Vista 32bit*.

Comment: Same result in 9.0.1. Odd behavior indeed; seems hard to justify it as anything other than a bug...

Comment: Try `BinCounts[lst + $MachineEpsilon, {Range[0, 18]}]`... looks bug-like to me. You can use `N`, or `Length /@ BinLists[lst, {Range[0, 18]}]` as work-around.

Comment: same result in OSX v9.0.1

Comment: But `HistogramList[lst, {Range[0, 18]}]` works ok.

Comment: another way to fix: `BinCounts[lst, {Append[Range[0, 18], Infinity]}]`

Comment: minimal example: `BinCounts[{0, 3, Sqrt[2]}, {Range[1, 2]}] -> {0} `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has been fixed in *v10.0* (Tested on *Wolfram Programming Cloud*):

[image]

Comment: In MMA V10 desktop version it's ok too.